# Need to fetch records from oracle db table in specific order

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

i have table in oracle, which can have following data in it

```
W_ID        S_ID         SEQ      Type
1           Template1     1        W
1           Template2     2        W
1           1             3        S
Template1   2             1        S
Template1   3             2        S
Template2   4             1        S
Template2   5             2        S
Template2   6             3        S
```

Now i want S_ID for W_Id=1 order by SEQ
means i want to fetch first results of Template1 after that Template2

result should be as follows :

```
S_ID  SEQ
2     1
3     2
4     1
5     2
6     3
1     3
```

i have written the query as follows

```
select W_ID, S_ID, SEQ from Table1 where 

  W_ID in (select S_ID from Table1 where W_ID='1' and Type='W') 
  or 
  (S_ID in (select S_ID from Table1 where W_ID='1' and Type='S') and W_ID='1')

order by SEQ
```

Now problem is i am not able to fetch result in order
please help,

Ragards,
Yogesh

Comment: One suspects that the columns are somehow related to each other.  Can you better explain the layout of the table?

Comment: Yes, in table1 W_ID can have Templates assign to it as S_ID, in this case its Type is W. W_ID can also have direct S_ID also, in this its Type is S. if Type is W then that S_ID must have extention. means template can further have S_ID assign to it whose Type is S. Now i want to get S_ID in SEQ order. Template1 has SEQ as 1 so its records would fetched first, Template2 has SEQ as 2 so its records would fetch later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want it sorted first by template seq, then individual type 'S' seq. That is possible by joining:

```
select t1.w_id
     , case t1.type when 'W' then t2.s_id else t1.s_id end s_id
     , case t1.type when 'W' then t2.seq  else t1.seq  end seq
  from table1 t1
  left outer join table1 t2
      on t1.type = 'W'
      and t2.w_id = t1.s_id
      and t2.type = 'S'
 where t1.w_id = '1'
 order by t1.seq, t2.seq
```

---

The extra functionality asked for can be done with analytic functions:

```
select w_id
     , s_id
     , seq
  from (
   select t1.w_id
        , case t1.type when 'W' then t2.s_id else t1.s_id end s_id
        , case t1.type when 'W' then t2.seq  else t1.seq  end seq
        , t1.seq t1seq
        , t2.seq t2seq
        , row_number() over (
             partition by
                t1.w_id
              , case t1.type when 'W' then t2.s_id else t1.s_id end
             order by
                t1.seq, t2.seq
          ) rn
     from table1 t1
     left outer join table1 t2
         on t1.type = 'W'
         and t2.w_id = t1.s_id
         and t2.type = 'S'
    where t1.w_id = '1'
  )
 where rn = 1
 order by t1seq, t2seq
```

There may be simpler ways - this was just what I could think of quickly ;-)

Comment: One more query, if i want distinct s_id then what should be added in query. means for ex: if template1 has s_id 6 while template2 also has s_id 6 mapped in it. but the seq of template1 was 1 and template2 is 2, so i want 6 from template1 only. how to achieve this? please help

Comment: awesome man... really awesome !!! Too good. i am really impressed with you. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just need a self join to get desired result:

```
with table1(W_ID,S_ID,SEQ,Type) as (
  select '1', 'Template1', 1, 'W' from dual union all 
  select '1', 'Template2', 2, 'W' from dual union all 
  select '1', '1', 3, 'S' from dual union all 
  select 'Template1', '2', 1, 'S' from dual union all 
  select 'Template1', '3', 2, 'S' from dual union all 
  select 'Template2', '4', 1, 'S' from dual union all 
  select 'Template2', '5', 2, 'S' from dual union all 
  select 'Template2', '6', 3, 'S' from dual)
----------
-- End if Data
----------
select a.S_ID a_s_id, b.s_id b_s_id, b.seq 
  from table1 a
  join table1 b on a.s_id = b.w_id
 where a.w_id = '1'
   and (a.type='W' or a.w_id = b.s_id)
   and b.type='S'
 order by a.seq, b.s_id;
```

Output:

```
|    A_S_ID | B_S_ID | SEQ |
|-----------|--------|-----|
| Template1 |      2 |   1 |
| Template1 |      3 |   2 |
| Template2 |      4 |   1 |
| Template2 |      5 |   2 |
| Template2 |      6 |   3 |
|         1 |      1 |   3 |
```

Update:

After changing the sequence also, it works fine (from comment section :-> "**changed sequence of S_Id=1 to 2 and make the sequence of template2 as 3 then result should be records of template1 then records of S_Id 1 then record of template2 in this fashion**)

```
with table1(W_ID,S_ID,SEQ,Type) as (
      select '1', 'Template1', 1, 'W' from dual union all 
      select '1', 'Template2', 3, 'W' from dual union all 
      select '1', '1', 2, 'S' from dual union all 
      select 'Template1', '2', 1, 'S' from dual union all 
      select 'Template1', '3', 2, 'S' from dual union all 
      select 'Template2', '4', 1, 'S' from dual union all 
      select 'Template2', '5', 2, 'S' from dual union all 
      select 'Template2', '6', 3, 'S' from dual)
----------
-- End if Data
----------
select a.S_ID a_s_id, b.s_id b_s_id, b.seq 
  from table1 a
  join table1 b on a.s_id = b.w_id
 where a.w_id = '1'
   and (a.type='W' or a.w_id = b.s_id)
   and b.type='S'
 order by a.seq, b.s_id;
```

output:

```
|    A_S_ID | B_S_ID | SEQ |
|-----------|--------|-----|
| Template1 |      2 |   1 |
| Template1 |      3 |   2 |
|         1 |      1 |   2 |
| Template2 |      4 |   1 |
| Template2 |      5 |   2 |
| Template2 |      6 |   3 |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot San, Thank you very much....this solves my problem partially. It works fine for Template1 and Template2 and all subsequent records of it. but using this i am not able to get the direct records assign to W_ID i.e in our scenario record with S_ID = 1. pls help

Comment: Hi.. Isn't the last record fetched from the query is the one you are looking for? The `or` condition used in the query serves the purpose. If not, then let me know.

Comment: Hi, i am not able to fetch the last record with S_ID = 1. can you plz look in to it ?

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns? Can you update your question with the table's ddl? Is there any space character in w_id or s_id?

Comment: W_ID and S_ID both are varchar2

Comment: For me its working fine check this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8660c/1), I am not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: but if i change the sequence then it not works. i changed sequence of S_Id=1 to 2 and make the sequence of template2 as 3 then result should be records of template1 then records of S_Id 1 then record of template2 in this fashion. but it not gives that properly. please help

Comment: Again I get the desired result with the same query, I have included the S_ID for both for clearer understanding. Check the Answer, I have updated it.

Comment: hi, if i change S_ID to non matching W_Id then unmatched row wont be return. for ex: i made S_ID to 12 then we can not get desired results. currentely it is matching because both S_Id=w_id=1. please help

Comment: In that case, did you tried the another answer given by `Kim Berg Hansen`? I think that will suffice your requirement.

Comment: Hi San, answer given by Kim Berg Hansen works perfectly fine for me. thanks a lot for your support. really very thankful to you...